# Unable to manually configure apache httpd 2.4.12 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apache, load-balancing, httpd.conf, ubuntu-13.10

I need to manually install apache httpd 2.4.12 on ubuntu 13.10. For some reasons I cannot use apt-get install.

Having gone through the instructions provided for httpd installation, I execute the following commands in order

1. Unzip the installation that was downloaded
2. Navigate to the folder where the installation is present till the bin folder
3. Within the bin folder execute ./configure with the needed parameters.
4. make (Error occurs here. Unable to proceed further)
5. make install

When I execute the make command, I get this error

```
**make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.**
```

Anyone has any idea where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either are

1. in the wrong folder (no `Makefile`)
2. failed to properly `./configure` (any errors?)

`configure` is responsible for generating the `Makefile`s. If you don't succeed at configuring (maybe you are missing some library needed for compilation?) then you won't get `Makefile`s and cannot call `make`.

**Never** ignore errors. They are errors, after all. They'll come back to bite you.

Comment: you are right. I did not locate one error which was lost in the stack.